# Ratio of odd to even or even to odd polynomial

Tags: polynomials, even-and-odd-functions

If given two polynomials such that p(s) is even and q(s) is odd then what can we conclude about the division of these polynomials. Will they become odd or even? I think both become odd. Is it true?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what does it mean "Will they become odd or even?". Are you talking about the quotient of the two and its parity? If that is the case do they have common roots? If yes, how many? Is this an odd or an even number? These are possible cases you can split your problem in, if I understand correctly.

Comment: It’s not even clear what you mean by “odd polynomial” or “even”. Do you mean to refer to the degrees of the polynomials, or whether $p(-s)=-p(s)$ versus  $\,=p(s)$ ?